# Making mongoose queries work with bluebird's reflect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am trying to use Bluebird with mongoose. Here is my implementation.

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Entity = require('./entity');
mongoose.Promise = Bluebird;
```

Now I try to do something like this.

```
let promises = [];
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'HONGKONG' }));
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'INDIA' }));
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'THAILAND' }));
```

I know the above query doesn't make sense. It's just an example for multiple promise.

Now I try to implement Bluebirds reflect

```
return Bluebird.all(promises.map(function (promise) {
  return promise.reflect();
}))
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.filter(r => r.isFulfilled() ));
    console.log(response.filter(r => !r.isFulfilled() ));
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
  })
```

I get error `promise.reflect is not a function`

But, When I do this, It works fine.

```
promises.push(new  Bluebird( (resolve, reject) => resolve(Entity.findOne({ country: 'HONGKONG' } )) ));
promises.push(new  Bluebird( (resolve, reject) => resolve(Entity.findOne({ country: 'INDIA' } )) ));
promises.push(new  Bluebird( (resolve, reject) =>  resolve(Entity.findOne({ country: 'THAILAND' } )) ));
```

My question is, Why mongoose is not taking bluebird's promise implementation normally. Do I need to explicitly resolve each query with Bluebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it fails because [.findOne()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) does not return a Promise, but a Query Object. You have to add [.exec()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) at the end.

Try:

```
let promises = [];
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'HONGKONG' }).exec());
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'INDIA' }).exec());
promises.push(Entity.findOne({ country: 'THAILAND' }).exec());
```

[Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) you have more information about Promises in Mongoose. Why you need to use the `.exec()` function is explained as well.